# Special characters showing in Vi editor but not with cat command

Tags: shell, unix

I've an application log file. When I open the log file in Vi editor I could see special characters whereas when I do a cat command the special characters don't showup.

I tried redirecting the results of cat command to an output file but the special characters are still showing up.

Could you please help me understand the behavior and how to remove/resolve the special characters.  Greatly appreciate your help.

**With Vi editor :**

```
[ec2-user@ip-##-##-##-### 20230606 15:57:16 ~]$ vi ipcTempFile.log
sh-4.2$ cd trila^G^H^[[K^H^[[Ka^Gl^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^G^Gmore trial^G.csv
West Ham are massive
Chennai Super Kings
Manchester City
Chelsea
Real Madrid
```

**With Cat Command :**

```
[ec2-user@ip-##-##-##-### 20230606 15:54:33 ~]$ cat ipcTempFile.log
sh-4.2$ more trial.csv
West Ham are massive
Chennai Super Kings
Manchester City
Chelsea
Real Madrid
```

**After redirecting Cat Command results to output file:**

```
[ec2-user@ip-##-##-##-### 20230606 16:24:07 ~]$ cat ipcTempFile.log > ipcTempFile_modified.log
[ec2-user@ip-##-##-##-### 20230606 16:24:22 ~]$ cat -v ipcTempFile_modified.log
sh-4.2$ cd trila^G^H^[[K^H^[[Ka^Gl^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^G^Gmore trial^G.csv ^M
West Ham are massive^M
Chennai Super Kings^M
Manchester City^M
Chelsea^M
Real Madrid^M
```

Comment: `man cat` in the future. `cat -vet file` may solve your problem. Good luck.

Comment: The file seemd to contain keyboard input or terminal output that contains control characters or escape sequences like cursor or function keys or cursor positioning.